# Force.com Web Service Connectors for Maven Repo

Tags: force.com, soap-api, tooling-api

The Java jars generated from WSDLs and posted to [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api) have been awesome.

**Questions:**

1. Who maintains this repo?
2. Could we also make public the web service connectors for the Apex and tooling APIs?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

There are two open source accounts that we have in the public where we welcome contributions and pull requests as salesforce.com.

Any official open source projects produced by salesforce.com R&D can be found here: 
https://github.com/forcedotcom

Smaller projects produced by the developer relations teams can be found here:
https://github.com/developerforce

Finally salesforce.com are the originators of and active contributors to an apache commons project called Phoenix which you can find here:
http://phoenix.apache.org/

I'm not certain what you mean by the "Apex" API? Do you mean the Apex programming language that runs on the platform? If so, there are no plans in the near future to open source this feature as of yet. Nor are there plans to open source the standard APIs like the tooling API. It could happen one day, just nothing in the foreseeable future.

Comment: The docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector still refer to the old Google Code repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can donwload from the maven repository:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc/29.0.0